# The activation and achentication flow in django

Tags: django, django-registration

I Am using Django on my website, and using django-registartion for the activation flow.

I am not quite sure if thats how it should behave. on my site , the user fill in the registration form , activation email is forward to his email. When the user click on the activation link, he reached activation complete state.

However, The user in that moment needs to login. Is that how it should work? or should an actiivation complete state also login the user to the system ?

Comment: After activation complete user can login, otherwise system will prompt that account is inactive on login page.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear. My question is if after clicking on the link in the email and redirect to the activation link, Does it make sense that he is not automaticly authenticated ? and still need to login in ?

Comment: No it will not authenticate user automatically, user have to go to login page and enter credentials.

Comment: Is that a common acitivation procedure ? Or it just a django-registartion implementation. I am trying to think why not authenticate the user after the activation...

Comment: Its common activation procedure. If you wish you can override, the activation view in your view and authenticate user after the activation.